# How to use subdomain route with zf2 ?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, dns, zend-framework2

I am trying to use subdomain route in zf2, but getting dns error. I have added a route like this :

```
'testSubDomain' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Hostname',
                        'options' => array(
                                'route'    => ':blog.mydomain.net',
                        ),
                        'may_terminate' => false,
                        'child_routes' => array(
                                'home' => array(
                                        'type' => 'Literal',
                                        'options' => array(
                                                'route'    => '/',
                                                'defaults' => array(
                                                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Solution',
                                                        'action'     => 'testSubdomain'
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                ),
```

I have created apache vhost and the configurations of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf are as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName mydomain.net
        ServerAlias mydomain.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/beta/public

        <directory /var/www/beta/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

        </directory>

        <Directory /var/www/beta/public>
                Options -Indexes
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
----------
Some other vhost
-----------
```

When I go to blog.mydomain.net it is showing server DNS address could not be found. I haven't defined any vhost for subdmoain in 000-default.conf so it should use the first one. I have also added one A record for the subdomain but it is also not working.

Comment: any updates? Did you find solution?

Comment: @marcel-djaman Yes I am able to use subdomain .

Comment: did you add a virtual host or just a simple line in /etc/hosts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution posted in this question is correct, somethings need to keep in mind. Don't create a Vhost for your subdomain, but your subdomain should point to the serer. If you create a vhost for subdomain then it will follow the appplication modules config route and show you the homepage.

```
'testSubDomain' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Hostname',
                        'options' => array(
                                'route'    => 'blog.mydomain.net',
                        ),
                        'may_terminate' => false,
                        'child_routes' => array(
                                'home' => array(
                                        'type' => 'Literal',
                                        'options' => array(
                                                'route'    => '/',
                                                'defaults' => array(
                                                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Solution',
                                                        'action'     => 'testSubdomain'
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                ),
```

When you go to blog.mydomain.net it will show you the content of testSubdomain function. **No need to create any vhost for subdomain.**